# assistance with tic tac toe assignment

Tags: java, arrays, validation

I can't get the game to call it a draw or win diagonally, I'm almost done but I can't figure it out. I've tried everything. I can win the game in straight lines but diagonally doesn't seem to finish in the loop. And I'm not sure if it ever reaches the loop for the full board or completes it even though it should.

```
import java.util.Scanner; //Used for player's input in game



public class TicTacToe 
{   
//instance variables
private char[][] board; //Tic Tac Toe Board, 2d array
private boolean xTurn; // true when X's turn, false if O's turn
private Scanner input; // Scanner for reading input from keyboard

//Constants for creation of gameboard
public final int ROWS = 3; //total rows
public final int COLS = 3; //total columns
public final int WIN = 3; //amount needed to win

public TicTacToe()

{
    //creates the board
    board = new char[ROWS][COLS];

    for(int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < COLS; c++)
        {   
            board[r][c] = ' ';
        }
    }

    //X's turn when game starts
    xTurn = true; 

    //creates our input object for the turn player
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
}

    //shows game board
public void displayBoard()

{   
 int colNum = 0; //number of columns
 int rowNum = 0; //number of rows

//creates column labels
System.out.println(" \n");
System.out.println("     Columns ");
for (int num = 0; num < COLS; num++)
{
    System.out.print("   " + colNum);
    colNum++;
}

//creates vertical columns and spaces between each spot 
System.out.println(" \n");
for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) 
{
    //numbers rows
    System.out.print(" " + rowNum + "  ");
    rowNum++;

    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; ++col) 
    {
        System.out.print(board[row][col]); // print each of the cells
        if (col != COLS - 1) 
        {
            System.out.print(" | ");   // print vertical partition
        }   
    }

    System.out.println();

    //creates seperation of rows
    if (row != ROWS - 1) 
    {
        System.out.println("   ------------"); // print horizontal partition
    }
}

    //labels row
    System.out.println("Rows \n");

}

    //displays turn player
public void displayTurn()
{
    if (xTurn)
    {
        System.out.println("X's Turn");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("O's Turn");
    }
}

    //allows you to make move
public boolean playerMove()
{
    boolean invalid = true;
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;

    while(invalid)
    {
        System.out.println("Which row (first) then column (second) would you like to \n"
                           + "play this turn? Enter 2 numbers between 0-2 as \n"
                           + "displayed on the board, seperated by a space to \n"
                           + "choose your position.");

        if (input.hasNextInt())
        {
            row = input.nextInt();

            if (row > ROWS - 1|| row < 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid position");
                    playerMove();
                }

            else if (row >= 0 && row <= ROWS - 1 && column >= 0 && column <= COLS - 1)
            {
                if (board[row][column] != ' ')
                {
                    System.out.println("Spot is taken \n");
                }

                else
                {
                    invalid = false;
                }
            }
            if(input.hasNextInt())
            {
                column = input.nextInt();

                if (column > COLS - 1|| column < 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid position");
                  playerMove();
                }

                //checks if spot is filled
                else if (row >= 0 && row <= ROWS - 1 && column >= 0 && column <= COLS - 1)
                {
                    if (board[row][column] != ' ')
                    {
                        System.out.println("Spot is taken \n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        invalid = false;
                    }
                }    
            }
        }


        //fills spot if not taken
        if (xTurn)
        {
            board[row][column] = 'X';
        }

        else
        {
            board[row][column] = 'O';
        }
    }
        return displayWinner(row,column);       
}

public boolean displayWinner(int lastR, int lastC)
{
    boolean winner = false;
    int letter = board[lastR][lastC];

    //checks row for win
    int spotsFilled = 0;
    for (int c = 0; c < COLS; c++)
    {
        if(board[lastR][c] == letter)
        {
            spotsFilled++;
        }
    }

    if (spotsFilled == WIN)
    {
        winner = true;
    }

    //checks columns for win
    spotsFilled = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
    {
        if(board[r][lastC] == letter)
        {
            spotsFilled++;
        }
    }

    if (spotsFilled == WIN)
    {
        winner = true;
    }

    //checks diagonals for win
    spotsFilled = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < WIN; i++)
    {
        if(board[i][i] == letter)
        {
            spotsFilled++;
        }
    }

    if(spotsFilled == WIN)
    {
        winner = true;
    }

    //checks other diagonal
    spotsFilled = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < WIN; i++)
    {
        if(board[i][COLS - ( i + 1)] == letter)
        {
            spotsFilled++;
        }
    }

    if(spotsFilled == WIN)
    {
        winner = true;
    }

    return winner;
}

//checks if board is full
public boolean fullBoard()
{
    int filledSpots = 0;

    for(int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < COLS; c++)
        {
            if (board[r][c] == 'X' || board[r][c] == 'O')
            {
                filledSpots++;
            }
        }
    }
    return filledSpots == ROWS*COLS;
}

//plays game
public void playGame()
{
    boolean finish = true;
    System.out.println("Are your ready to start?");
    System.out.println("1 for Yes or 0 for No? : ");

    if (input.hasNextInt())
    {
        int choice = input.nextInt();

        if(choice > 1 || choice < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid choice");
        playGame();
    }

    else if (choice == 1)
    {
        while (finish)
        {
            displayBoard();
            displayTurn();

            if (playerMove())
            {
                displayBoard();
                if (xTurn)
                {
                    System.out.println("X won");
                    displayBoard();
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("O won");
                    displayBoard();
                }
            }

            else if (fullBoard())
            {
                displayBoard(); 
                System.out.println("Draw");
            }  
            else
            {
                //no winner, switching turns
                xTurn=!xTurn;
            }
        }
    }
}        
    else 
    {   
        System.out.println("Input not valid");

    }
}
}
```

and the tester

```
public class TicTacToeTester {

/**
 * @param 
 * args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    TicTacToe tictactoe = new TicTacToe();

    tictactoe.playGame();
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take some time to visit the [help] and also read [ask].  Questions of the form "here's my code, please debug it" are considered off-topic. StackOverflow is not a discussion, tutorial or debugging site. The way this works is you are expected to attempt to solve the problem and then ask for help when you run into a difficulty, explaining clearly what you have tried and what you don't understand. At a minimum you should already have stepped through the code in an IDE debugger and be able to identify results that don't match your expectation.

Comment: How do you use the debugger? Is there a site that explains it?

Comment: Did you try Googling "[how to use eclipse debugger java](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)"?

Comment: I use netbeans for now. Would eclipse be better or it doesnt really matter?

Comment: Google "how to use Netbeans debugger"